# Need help mass renaming files using command line that contain a certain string

Tags: command-line, ssh, filesystem, rename, batch-rename

I have about 200 files that are named like this:

```
01_-_Back_Alley_Uproar.avi
01_-_Bad_Luck_Cat.avi
01_-_Beep_Beep.avi
02_-_Broomstick_Bunny.avi
02_-_Bunker_Hill.avi
```

and so on.  I would like to rename them all to look like this:

```
Back Alley Uproar.avi
Bad Luck Cat.avi
Beep Beep.avi
Broomstick Bunny
Bunker Hill
```

and so on...

I need to use the command line as I am connected via ssh via winSCP from a windows box to get to my ubuntu server containing these files.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rename` command, with appropriate regular expressions e.g.

```
s/^\d+_-_//
```

for 'replace an initial sequence of digits followed by underscore hyphen underscore'; and

```
s/_/ /g
```

to replace underscores with spaces. So

```
rename -nv 's/^\d+_-_//;s/_/ /g' *.avi
```

The `-n` makes it run in test (dry run) mode - test it in your directory and if you are happy that it's doing the right thing, run it without the `n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
rename 's/[0-9]+_-_//; s/_/\ /g' *
```